# GitHub actions: if conditionals in execution of step fails

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to run a GitHub actions step if an env var matches a value

```
      - name: send slack failure
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
        if: env.STATUS_MESSAGE != "Success"
```

However the above syntax is marked as error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/file.yaml (Line: 107, Col: 13): Unexpected symbol: '"Success"'. Located at position 23 within
```

How can I compare the value of the env var to a given value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
if: ${{ env.STATUS_MESSAGE != 'Success' }}
```

`${{` and `}}` are optional